# R: adjusting a given time-series but keeping summary statistics equal

Tags: r, data-generation

Let's say I have a time-series like this

```
t       x
1       100
2       50
3       200
4       210
5       90
6       80
7       300
```

Is it possible in R to generate a new dataset `x1` which has the exact same summary statistics, e.g. mean, variance, kurtosis, skew as `x`?

The reason for my asking is that I would like to do an experiment where I want to test how subjects react to different graphs of data that contain the same information.

I recently read:

- Matejka, Justin, and George Fitzmaurice. "Same stats, different graphs: Generating datasets with varied appearance and identical statistics through simulated annealing." Proceedings of the 2017 CHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems. ACM, 2017.
- Generating Data with Identical Statistics but Dissimilar Graphics: A Follow up to the Anscombe Dataset, The American Statistician, 2007,

However, Matejka uses code in Python that is quite scientific and their data is more complex than time-series data, so I was wondering if there was a way to do this more efficiently for a simpler data set?

Best regards

Comment: If I am not mistaken this question has nothing to do with time series. I'll remove the tag.

Comment: Check out the [`datasauRus` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datasauRus/index.html) and its corresponding [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datasauRus/vignettes/Datasaurus.html)

Comment: Hi Jason, I cannot import my own data into datasauRus unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a package that can give you precisely what you are looking for. One option is using the datasets in the `datasauRus` package as JasonAizkalns pointed out. However, if you want to create your own dataset, you can try this:
Fit the `Johnson distribution` from the `SuppDists` package to get the moments of the dataset and draw new sets from that distribution until the difference is sufficiently small. Below an example with your dataset, although more observations make it easier to replicate the summary statistics:

```
library(SuppDists)
a <- c(100,50,200,210,90,80,300)

momentsDiffer <- function(x1,x2){
  diff <- sum(abs(moments(x1)- moments(x2)))
  return(diff)
}

repDataset <- function(x,n){
  # fit Johnson distribution
  parms<-JohnsonFit(a, moment="quant")
  # generate from distribution n times storing if improved
  current <- rJohnson(length(a),parms)
  momDiff <- momentsDiffer(x,current)
  for(i in 1:n){
    temp <- rJohnson(length(a),parms)
    tempDiff <- momentsDiffer(x,temp)
    if(tempDiff < momDiff){
      current <- temp
      momDiff <- tempDiff
    }
  }
  return(current)
}

# Drawing 1000 times to allow improvement
b <- repDataset(a,1000)
> moments(b)
        mean        sigma         skew         kurt 
148.14048691  84.24884165   1.04201116  -0.05008629 

> moments(a)
       mean       sigma        skew        kurt 
147.1428571  84.1281821   0.5894543  -1.0198303
```

**EDIT - Added additional method**
Following the suggestion of @Jj Blevins, the method below generates a random sequence based upon the original sequence leaving out 4 observations. Those 4 observations are then added through solving a non-linear equation on the difference between the four moments of the original sequence and the new sequence. This still not generate a perfect match, feel free to improve.

```
library(nleqslv)
library(e1071)
set.seed(1)
a <- c(100,50,200,210,90,80,300)
#a <- floor(runif(1000,0,101))

init <- floor(runif(length(a)-4,min(a),max(a)+1))
moments <- moments(a)

f <- function(x) {
  a <- mean(c(init,x))
  b <- var(c(init,x))
  c <- skewness(c(init,x))
  d <- kurtosis(c(init,x))
  c(a-moments[1],b-moments[2],c-moments[3],d-moments[4])
}
result <- nleqslv(runif(4,min(a),max(a)+1), f,control=list(ftol=.00000001, allowSingular=TRUE))

> moments(c(init,result$x))
       mean       sigma        skew        kurt 
49.12747961 29.85435993  0.03327868 -1.25408078 

> moments(a)
       mean       sigma        skew        kurt 
49.96600000 29.10805462  0.03904256 -1.18250616
```

Comment: thank you very much, I will try to use this and give give feedback later. The code line: momDiff <- momentsDiffer(x,initial) should be momDiff <- momentsDiffer(x,current) if I am not mistaken, correct?

Comment: do you think it would be somehow possible to design your own graphs but keeping the summary statistics equal? For example by setting certain data points as fixed and only adjusting the rest?

Comment: @JjBlevins, added a trial method on that. Not a complete match, but it does seem possible when further improved.

Comment: I used the code now using my data set which is a vector of 250 daily returns, ranging from -0.036 to 0.036. Using the Johnson method by drawing 1,000,000 times gives me a good solution for the moments except for the mean, which is quite off. Do you have an idea why especially a similar mean cannot be found?

Comment: I have no explanation why that is, besides that differences in the other moments are probably harder to correct. But... it's quite easy to change the mean without changing the other moments, just subtract the difference between the current mean and the required mean from the dataset.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty dumb of me or pretty genius of you. Thank you very much, this actually solves the problem!

Comment: Would you have additional advice on how to keep some values fixed? I.e. those values should not be drawn from the Johnson distribution.

Comment: You can replace the line `current <- rJohnson(length(a),parms)` with something that keeps a vector of fixed values. E.g. assuming the vector is called `fixed`, you can use `current <- c(fixed,rJohnson(length(a)-length(fixed),parms))`